# output of the \usepackage{showframe} command

Tags: margins

I'm using a twoside document and want to check my binding clearance. What does this output represent?

[image]

[image]

Comment: header box, marginpar box, text area and footer baseline.

Comment: Can you read the documentation of `showframe` packge? You can get it by typing `texdoc showframe` in `MS-DOS` prompt ...

Comment: @MadyYuvi `texdoc showframe` does not work, please try!

Comment: Very helpful chaps, I'm asking here because I have read the documentation and am still unsure...

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [LaTeX/Page Layout](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout) of Wikibooks and you'll find this picture:

[image]

With this legend:

1. one inch + \hoffset
2. one inch + \voffset
3. \oddsidemargin = 31pt
4. \topmargin = 20pt
5. \headheight = 12pt
6. \headsep = 25pt
7. \textheight = 592pt
8. \textwidth = 390pt
9. \marginparsep = 10pt
10. \marginparwidth = 35pt
11. \footskip = 30pt

- \marginparpush = 7pt (not shown)
- \hoffset = 0pt
- \voffset = 0pt
- \paperwidth = 597pt
- \paperheight = 845pt